# Brackets When I Add Weights To Random Command

Tags: python, discord.py

I tried to add weights to my random code. I managed to add weights but the response had brackets in it. Can someone please help me? Thanks!

```
@bot.command()
async def sus(ctx):
    dre = ["Cyan faked trash!",
            "Red was following me!",
            "White vented right in front of me!",
            "Pink is so sus",
            "Brown sabotaged the reactor!",
            "**ELECTRICAL**",
            "Purple is the- oh, he's dead.",
            ]
    await ctx.send(f'{random.choices(dre, weights=(500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 100, 500))}')
```

Comment: What is the output?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: What happens when you run the command, what message does the bot send?

Comment: Oh, it sends: ['Pink is so sus']

Comment: Have you tried `random.choice` instead of `random.choices`?

Comment: Yes i have, it gave an error and the command didnt work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`random.choices` always returns a list.  Since that list will always contain a single item, you can just use the first element every time:

```
choice = random.choices(dre, weights=(500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 100, 500))[0]
await ctx.send(choice)
```